# execute c# code after jquery dialog OK button is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I have an asp.net web page that has a search button.When the button is clicked, a jquery dialog box appears and the user must either confirm that they want to continue or cancel.If they click the Confirm button, the c# code behind the Search button must continue to be executed and if they click cancel, the dialog must be closed and nothing else happens.The jQuery i am using to display the modal pop up is below

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=butSearch.ClientID%>").click(function (e) { // Button which will activate our modal
            $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                animationspeed: 600,                       // how fast animtions are
                closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
                dismissmodalclass: 'close'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
            });
            return false;
        });
    });


<div id="modal">
    <div id="heading">
         Search Notification
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Please be aware that any search via the xxxx, will incur a cost. Do you wish to proceed?</p>

        <a href="#" class="button green close"><img src="../../Imgs/dialog_tick.png">Proceed</a>
        <a href="#" class="button red close"><img src="../../Imgs/dialog_cross.png">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what's the actual *problem*?

Comment: what has modal pop up to do with that?

Comment: My actual problem is how do i get my code to continue to execute after the Confirm button on the modal pop up dialog is cliecked

Comment: does not your modal pop up have anything besides the confirmation?

Comment: You'd probably have to link the accept with an Ajax call, which invokes a C# Script to do the result of the operation, or a `<form>` within the modal if you can edit that.

Comment: why don't you use a simple confirmation provided in javascript, i mean the default one. Do you have specific design requirements? can't you do away with modal pop up after all its only for confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm looking at the [right plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin), there does not appear to be any option you can pass to this plugin to respond differently to the close button configured.

There is, however, no reason not to attach an event to the button you're interested in performing some other action. In your case im thinking that's the proceed button, and you want to make an ajax call to the server:

```
$('#modal .button.green.close').click(function(){
   $.ajax(...)
});
```

In that example, `$.ajax` can be substituted for any of the jquery ajax methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can try this first make sure the modal pop up is appended inside 
form and then simply cause form submit with jQuery in case user clicks on Proceed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=butSearch.ClientID%>").click(function (e) { // Button which will activate our modal
        $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
            animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 600,                       // how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
        });
        jQuery("#modal").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")); // This will append the dialog to the form ensuring values are sent during postback.
        return false;
    });
}); 



<div id="modal">
<div id="heading">
     Search Notification
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p>Please be aware that any search via the xxxx, will incur a cost. Do you wish to proceed?</p>

    <a href="#" id="anchorProceed" onclick="javascript:proceed()" class="button green close"><img src="../../Imgs/dialog_tick.png">Proceed</a>
    <a href="#" id="anchorCancel" class="button red close"><img src="../../Imgs/dialog_cross.png">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

```
function proceed(){
 $( "#yourFormID" ).submit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tariq.When i slick the Proceed button, it does not seem to be submitting the form.Is there a way of just continuing the execution of code behind the click event of the original Search button,

Comment: function proceed() {
            var formId = $('form').attr('id');
            $(formId).submit();
        }

Comment: you have to place your form id at this 'yourFormID', does it not work ?

Comment: thats what u r doing above

Comment: Yes thats what i am doing but the submit is not working.Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem.The page is a content page that inheriting from a master page and the form id that i am getting for the content page is not a valid form id hence the submit is failing.